# How flatten semi nested python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary like following:

```
score_dictionary={'Agriculture':89,'Health':{'Public':90,'Private':78},'Mines':70,'Commerce':67}
```

Using this dictionary, I want to convert to the following:

```
score_dictionary={'Agriculture':89,'Health_public':90,'Health_Private':78,'Mines':70,'Commerce':67}
```

Now I'm stuck at how to convert it?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `isinstance` to check whether or not the value in a given `key`/`value` pair consist in another dictionary, format the key name with string formatting and update accordingly:

```
d = {}
for k,v in score_dictionary.items():
    if not isinstance(v, dict):
        d[k] = v
    else:
        for k_, v_ in v.items():
            d[f'{k}_{k_}'] = v_
```

---

```
print(d)

{'Agriculture': 89,
 'Health_Public': 90,
 'Health_Private': 78,
 'Mines': 70,
 'Commerce': 67}
```

Comment: Can you pls explain `d[f'{k}_{k_}'] = v_` code ? what does it mean by f ?

Comment: These are `f-strings`, the new syntax for string formatting, check https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/ @moon

Comment: `f'stringhere'` is newer form of string-formatting. You could do the same thing with the following code: `d['{}_{}'.format(k, k_)] = v`